# How can I push data to an array in a JSON file and save it?

Tags: node.js, arrays, json, npm, node-modules

So im trying to push an array, to a JSON file which is already in an array format.

```
The code im using to attempt this is:

needle.get("https://bpa.st/raw/VHVQ", function(response, body){
     let testlist = require('../testlist.json') 
     let list = response.body;
     let listarray = list.split("\r\n")
     for (var i of listarray) {
     testlist.push(i);
     }
```

When my app is running it shows testlist.json as:

```
["1", "2", "this", "is", "an", "example", "for", "stackoverflow"]
```

Now it seems to work fine, it acts like its updated the array, but if I check, it hasn't, and if I restart my app then it resets to the original un-edited version.

```
testlist.json looks like this:

["1", "2"]
```

and after, im trying to make it edit the json file to look like this:

```
["1", "2", "this", "is", "an", "example", "for", "stackoverflow"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you import the contents of `testlist.json` into the variable `testlist` using `require()`, you are loading the file's contents into memory. You will need to write back to the file after you have made changes to the `testlist` variable if you want your modifications to persist. Otherwise, the changes that you make will be lost when the program's process exits.

You can use the `writeFileSync()` method from the `fs` module, as well as `JSON.stringify()`, to write `testlist` back into the `testlist.json` file:

```
const fs = require("fs");

let testlist = require("../testlist.json");

// Your code where you modify testlist goes here

// Convert testlist to a JSON string
const testlistJson = JSON.stringify(testlist);
// Write testlist back to the file
fs.writeFileSync("../testlist.json", testlistJson, "utf8");
```

Edit: You should also use the `readFileSync()` method (also from the `fs` module), and `JSON.parse()` to perform the initial reading of the JSON file, rather than `require()`.

```js
// This line
let testlist = require("../testlist.json");

// Gets replaced with this line
let testlist = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("../testlist.json", "utf8"));
```

You have to use `JSON.parse` as well as `fs.readFileSync` because when you are reading the file, it is read as a string, rather than a JSON object.

Comment: ive edited it to show an issue that ive come across!

Comment: I've edited my answer to hopefully fix your issue with read-only. I also noticed that I incorrectly used `fs.writeFile`, rather than `fs.writeFileSync`, so I've included that now as well.

Comment: sorry but ive ran into another issue and edited it to show some more so we can finally figure this out!

Comment: You're getting that error because the file is not found at that path. Are you sure that the `testlist.json` file is located at that path (not in the same directory, but one directory up as you're using `../`).

Also, RE: your edit, you should call `writeFileSync()` outside and after the for-loop, otherwise you're writing to the file during each iteration, rather than once at the end.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't edit my response if you have follow-up errors. Either use a comment, or edit your original question (which I've done for you). :)